How to override PostgreSQL's now() function for testing?
I'm working on a project that heavily relies on timestamp-based operations, and I need to write some tests that involve the now() function in PostgreSQL. For testing purposes, I want to be able to set a specific, hardcoded value for now()  (let's say December 31st 2027 noon) that persists until I manually reset it.
Specifically, I'm looking for a way to:

Set a custom value for now() at the beginning of my test suite
Have all calls to now() return this custom value throughout my tests
Reset now() to its normal behavior after the test(s) are complete

I only need this functionality in my test database that I run locally, not in production.
Is there a way to achieve this in PostgreSQL? I've looked into using SET  and ALTER commands or creating custom functions, but there are tons of problems, either it's not working for the current session, or it gets reset almost immediately.
It seems like a very basic functionality for a proper test setup so I wonder if I'm doing something wrong.

FYI,  the value of now() stays the same in a given transaction. If you capture that value at the beginning then you can use it to compare to all subsequent calls in the transaction.

You can create your own copy of the now() function in a schema other than pg_catalog, then set search_path accordingly (pg_catalog is implicitly searched first, unless it is explicitly included in the search path):
postgres=# create function public.now() returns timestamp with time zone language sql
postgres-# return timestamp with time zone '2024-01-01 00:00:00';
CREATE FUNCTION
postgres=# set search_path="$user",public,pg_catalog;
SET
postgres=# show search_path ;
         search_path
-----------------------------
 "$user", public, pg_catalog
(1 row)

postgres=# select now();
          now
------------------------
 2024-01-01 00:00:00-05
(1 row)


obviously this relies on you not having any hard-coded schema names used in any custom functions / views etc.
